# How can one use .Net to authenticate a username and password against a Kerberos realm outside one's Windows domain?

Tags: c#, .net, kerberos

I have a set of WCF web services running on IIS.  My organization has a Kerberos realm running on Unix or some flavor thereof.  The two systems are completely separate, i.e. my Windows machines are part of their own AD domain which has no trust relationship with the Kerberos realm.  My ultimate goal is to create a WCF service that takes a username and password and validates them against our Kerberos realm.

Simple question (I hope): is there a .Net library out there that I can use in my WCF layer to authenticate a given username/password combination?

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what you are after:

IF that Kerberos realm has already LDAP (if not just add it) then you can use [`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) to access the LDAP of Kerberos and check a given username/password...